# WPF: UnauthorizedAccessException using anonymous methods

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Here is the thing, I want to create a simply app that copy many files from one site, and move them to another; but using async methods and create a new thread.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //progressBar1.Maximum = _FileInfoArray.Count;

    DispatcherTimer dt1 = new DispatcherTimer();
    foreach (FileInfo Fi in _FileInfoArray)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
        {
            DispatcherOperation _dispOp = progressBar1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(delegate()
            {

                File.Copy(txtdestino.Text, Fi.FullName, true);

                //progressBar1.Value = n;
                //txtstatus.Content = ("Copiados " + n.ToString() + " archivos");
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            ));
            _dispOp.Completed += new EventHandler(_dispOp_Completed);
        }
            ));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

UnauthorizedAccessException is throw! It says that I can't access to txtdestino content. Some clues?

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------Edited
This is the version with all the changes, get the same error :( any clues?

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //First: Build mynames
    List<string> mynames = new List<string>();
    foreach (FileInfo fi in _FileInfoArray)
    {
        mynames.Add(fi.FullName);
    }



    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
       {
          foreach (string fullname in mynames)
            {
            DispatcherOperation _dispOp = progressBar1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(delegate()
            {
                string destino = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullname));
                File.Copy(fullname, destino, true);
                //Some progressbar changes
            }
            ));
            _dispOp.Completed += new EventHandler(_dispOp_Completed);
          }
        }
                ));
        t.Start();
    }
```

---

File.Copy(txtdestino.Text, Fi.FullName, true); // here the exception is throw

Comment: Where in the code is it throwing the Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple threads try to access (simultaneously) the file at `txtdestino.Text` - isn't that doomed from the start? You might want to read the contents into memory *first* and write from there...

Equally, you are going to hammer the IO; I wonder if a more practical answer (that solves the issue above **and** below) is to simply do the copies *sequentially* on the worker.

It also looks like you might actually be pushing all the work here back to the UI thread *anyway*...? surely you should do something like:

```
string path = txtdestino.Text;
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() {
    foreach (FileInfo Fi in _FileInfoArray) {
        File.Copy(path, Fi.FullName, true);
    }
}));
t.Start();
```

which:

- avoids the foreach/capture issue (`Fi` is not captured)
- reads the path from the UI thread and uses it (captured) on the worker
- process each file sequentially to avoid hammering IO

---

You also have the foreach/capture issue; change it to:

```
foreach (FileInfo tmp in _FileInfoArray)
{
    FileInfo Fi = tmp;
    ...
```

The problem is that most likely **all** the threads are trying to access the **last** file. No, really. This is because `foreach` *technically* declares the variable (`tmp` above) **outside** the loop; and the variable capture rules (used by lambdas / anon-methods) say that therefore this is the **same** variable (important: lambdas / anon-methods are full lexical closures, and capture the *variable*, not the *value*).

Re-declaring a variable *inside* the loop changes the scope, and now the lambda / anon-method treats the variable as different per loop iteration.

If you *really* want, I could write it out in something that shows the underlying objects involved, but it depends whether you want that level of detail ;p

Comment: Edited! I expect u can help me, it drives me crazy.

Comment: @Diego - silly question, but *does the user have permission to write to that target location* ? And read from the source?

Comment: of course, we are talking about the desktop of my pc! some suggestions?

Comment: @Diego, while it may be the desktop of your PC, on vista+windows7, the operating system tries to *discourage* writing to some locations, like the root of the drive, or `program files` directories, unless you're running as an admin.  Marc's question is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Calls to UI elements must be done in the UI thread. try getting the text value before your loop.

```
string txt = txtdestino.Text;
foreach (FileInfo Fi in _FileInfoArray)
{
    ....
    File.Copy(txt, Fi.FullName, true);
```

Comment: you need to remove any of the ui calls out of any of those delegates that will run in another thread.  no ui controls should be referenced from inside that code, so no referencing the textbox or progress bars/etc without `Dispatcher.Invoke` (or related) calls wrapped around them!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating multiple threads(1 for each file you find).
The problem is that only your main thread can access your form elements, otherwise all the threads would be changing your form elements at the same time.

Pass the value of txtdestino.Text to your new thread and you should be fine.